# How to find a $C^1$ vector field

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, surface-integrals

> Let $S=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=4\}$. Find a $C^1$ vector field ${\bf F}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that 
>   $$\iint_S {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}=\text{Area}(S).$$

I'm not even sure how to start this one...looking for a hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Take ${\bf F}$ orthogonal to the spherical surface such that
$${\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}=dS.$$

Comment: How do I do this when I don't know what F is?

Comment: What is an example of vector field orthogonal to the spherical surface $S$?

Comment: the normal vector

Comment: Then it should be easy to find ${\bf F}$ explicitely.